# xslt test with 2 parameters

Tags: xslt, umbraco

`<xsl:if test="count($currentPage/..//$itemType) &gt; 0">`

I try to use the if statement with 2 param values and I get the error:
"unexpected token '$' in the expression..."

is it possible to do what I'm trying to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT, like in most programming languages (excluding macro languages), variables represent values, not fragments of expression text. I suspect $itemType holds an element name, and you are imagining that you can use it anywhere you could use an element name. If that's what you are trying to do, use `..//*[name()=$itemType]`.

Answer (score 0):

**This is invalid** (and @Michael Kay explained it well):

```
//$varName
```

**If I guess correctly what you are up to, then you may try this**:

```
//*[name() = $varName]
```